# Selenium XPATH doesn't press a clickable button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

My problem is that the first on clicks while the second one doesn't and I don't understand why.

```
WebDriverWait(rootdiv, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@onclick[contains(.,JTC)]]")))

rootdiv.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@onclick[contains(.,'JTC')]]").click()

WebDriverWait(depdiv, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@onclick[contains(.,AJU)]]")))

depdiv.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@onclick[contains(.,'AJU')]]").click()
```

`depdiv` and `rootdiv` are children to find the certain li element in, because the root changes from the first to the second.
I've checked that the div is visible and in the first one, it does click, but the second time it can't find the object and a time error is raised.

Here is the part of the code I'm trying to fed from:

```
<div class = "divCombo4">
   <ul><li>....</li><ul>
   <ul><li>...</li><ul>
</div>
```

My `depdiv` is rooting to `find_element_by_id("divCombo4")`.

One of the ul li contains the following:

```
onclick="selecionou('AJU', this,'.txtBusca4', 'false', 'destino', 'Estouem2', 'AJU');"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a dot to make the expressions *context-specific*. Also, the `wait.until()` returns a `WebElement` instance and you can use it instead of issuing a "find element" command again:

```
WebDriverWait(rootdiv, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//li[@onclick[contains(.,JTC)]]"))).click()

WebDriverWait(depdiv, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//li[@onclick[contains(.,AJU)]]"))).click()
```